# How can I use RPC to locate the leg accounts for LP token?

Tags: spl-token, spl-associated-token-account, liquiditypool

I am working on a project that involves interacting with LP tokens, and I'm trying to locate the leg accounts associated with a specific LP token using RPC. Here is a static data what I need to get dynamically with rpc.

```
{
   "lp":"LPmSozJJ8Jh69ut2WP3XmVohTjL4ipR18yiCzxrUmVj",
   "underlying":[
      "mSoLzYCxHdYgdzU16g5QSh3i5K3z3KZK7ytfqcJm7So",
      "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112"
   ],
   "metadata":{
      "legA":"7GgPYjS5Dza89wV6FpZ23kUJRG5vbQ1GM25ezspYFSoE",
      "legB":"UefNb6z6yvArqe4cJHTXCqStRsKmWhGxnZzuHbikP5Q"
   }
}
```

I would like to know how to use RPC to find the leg accounts(also underlying) associated with this LP token. Specifically, I need guidance on the RPC calls or methods that can help me retrieve this information programmatically.

Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to gather some more information from the protocol that you're using. For example, you need to be able to deserialize a Raydium pool, or an Orca pool, to properly fetch that information. The protocols typically offer an SDK which allows users to do this programmatically. Here's Orca's SDK https://github.com/orca-so/whirlpools/tree/main/sdk and docs https://orca-so.gitbook.io/orca-developer-portal/orca/welcome as an example